# Litespeed - NextJS app in DigitalOcean Droplet - Restart Custom Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, digital-ocean, litespeed, pm2

Am using the DigitalOcean [OpenLiteSpeed NodeJS](https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/openlitespeed-nodejs) image from marketplace for setting up the Droplet, for running my NextJS app.

I have setup everything and when tested, the home page was displaying properly. When I clicked the Login button (that uses [NextAuth v4](https://next-auth.js.org/)) it was throwing an issue because of another package. So using `yarn`, I removed the package and re-installed it.

So after installation, I ran the `yarn build` (that executes `next build` command) and build was generated. But my question is, how do I restart the app? Will doing the **Graceful Restart** from the Litespeed admin console (https://myserverip:7080) is fine? I didn't done anything with the `PM2`. I mean I followed this video tutorial for deploying the NextJS app in the droplet: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IktnuT9UgbM and he didn't mentioned anything about the `PM2`

Let me know your thoughts. If this isn't the correct forum, please feel free to move this question that best suits. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a droplet, you can run `npm run start`. However, this forces you to leave the console open for the app to continue running.

Enter pm2. pm2 allows you to run the app in the background and allows you to persist the command if the droplet is rebooted (run on startup). So to restart the app, you run `pm2 restart` to restart whatever apps are configured. Run `pm2 status` to check what apps are configured and their status(es).

OLS is a web server like apache or nginx, which just controls what the public has access to... a Graceful Restart on OLS just allows you to pickup any changes made to OLS. It will not affect your app.